# Prevent line break after comment content

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display author name after the comment text without line breaks. The comment content is displayed using the `content_filter`. after some tests I was abel to see that the problem is coming from  `$qa_comment->content_filter` command, so my question is: How to prevent line break between the comment content and the author name. Here is the code that is in my wordpress theme explaining how comment content is being obtained

```
<div><?php echo $qa_comment->content_filter ?> –
     <span class="cmt-author">
          <a href="<?php echo $qa_comment->author_url ?>"  title="<?php echo $qa_comment->author ?>">
          <?php echo $qa_comment->author ?>
          </a>
     </span> 
</div>
```

Comment: Try putting your `$qa_comment->content_filter` in `span` tags ?

Comment: Have you written any css for `.cmt-author` selector which change its `display` property.

Comment: @Rick_Jellema Not working

Comment: @chanafdo I have removed the class cmt-author from the container and no changes.

Comment: How is `content_filter` stored/calculated

Comment: there is a class definition for qa_comment
`class QA_Comments {
 public static function convert($comment){
  $result->content_filter = apply_filters( 'the_content', $result->comment_content );
  return $result;
 }`

Comment: I can see that the comment content is inserted between the <p> tags. and I think that the solution is to remove these tags. I can't find the code responsible for this addition.

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS "display:inline-block"

HTML

```
<div><span><?php echo $qa_comment->content_filter ?> – </span>
    <span class="cmt-author">
    <a href="<?php echo $qa_comment->author_url ?>"  title="<?php echo $qa_comment->author ?>">
        <?php echo $qa_comment->author ?>
    </a>
    </span> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
div > span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Not working. Things are worse now; I get line breaks before and after the dash.